# Webmatrix - changing variable screws with search results

Tags: razor, pagination, webmatrix

i have a search page, which returns my results over a number of pages. This works really well. Here's the code:

```
//Paging Variables

var pageSize = 6; 
var totalPages = 0; 
var count = 0;
var page = UrlData[0].IsInt() ? UrlData[0].AsInt() : 1;
var offset = (page -1) * pageSize;

string selectQueryString =  "SELECT * FROM Property_Info";

queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString); 
count  = queryResults.Count();
totalPages = count/pageSize;        
if(count % pageSize > 0){
    totalPages += 1;
}

selectQueryString += "OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS  ONLY;";
queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, offset, pageSize);
```

The problem i have, is that i want to give users the option to change how many properties are shown on each page. To do this, i set the "pageSize" variable to 0, which changes depending on a query string.

The problem is, that paging stops working. When i move on to the second page, it shows me the same results as the first page?

Here's the querystring code:

```
//Set page size

if (Request.QueryString["pagesize"].AsInt() == 2)
{
    pageSize = 2;
} 
else
{
    pageSize = 4;
}
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: just a thought, is fetch/offset even the best method for this since i'm using SQL Express? I've just read that this is mainly used for SQL compact?

Comment: `OFFSET` and `FETCH` are supported by SQL Express starting from version 2012.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I'm not any closer to solving my issue, but it's good to know i'm not using the wrong code completely!

Comment: Can you show your code with it all combined? i.e. where have you put your 'querystring code'?

Comment: sure, i'll upload the full code and post the link.

Comment: Here you go. I've tried to cut out all the nonsense, but this is essentially what it boils down to. http://pastebin.com/p9gcyUaq

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code with the following small changes in conjunction with a SQL Server 2012 Express database:

```
@{
    var pageSize = Request.QueryString["pagesize"].AsInt() == 2 ? 2 : 4;
    var totalPages = 0; 
    var count = 0;
    var page = UrlData[0].IsInt() ? UrlData[0].AsInt() : 1;
    var offset = (page -1) * pageSize;

    var db = Database.Open("yourDb");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Property_Info";

    count = db.Query(selectQueryString).Count();
    totalPages = count/pageSize;        
    if(count % pageSize > 0){
        totalPages += 1;
    }

    selectQueryString += " OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS ONLY";    
    var queryResult = db.Query(selectQueryString, offset, pageSize);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body> 

        <p>Page @page of @totalPages</p>

        @foreach(var row in queryResult){
            // here your activities on rows ....
        }

        @{
            for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++){
            <a href="/search/@i@(Request.QueryString.ToString().Length == 0 ?
                null : "?" +   Request.QueryString)">@i</a>
            }
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

All works fine for me but I have seen from your link that the real code is far more complex.
Try starting from this working example and adding step by step your other code.